# What's the point of get an address of universal/forward reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

I come across following code [snippet](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Cpp-High-Performance/blob/master/Chapter11/parallel_transform_naive.cpp#L9):

```
......
template <typename SrcIt, typename DstIt, typename Func>
auto par_transform_naive(SrcIt first, SrcIt last, DstIt dst, Func&& func) {
    ......
    auto future = std::async([first, dst, start_idx, stop_idx, &func] {
      std::transform(first + start_idx, first + stop_idx, dst + start_idx, func);
    });
    ......
}
......
```

What confuses me is why the code needs to get an address of `func`:

```
......
auto future = std::async([first, dst, start_idx, stop_idx, &func]
......
```

Per my understanding, no matter `func` is deduced as `lvaule refernce` or `rvalue reference`, it is all no need to get an address again.

Comment: There's no such operation as "get a reference" in C++. The built-in `&` operator is "get an *address*" (it returns a pointer, not a reference). This `&` is not an operator though.

Comment: @n.m. Modify it, thanks! BTW, also my question is al little stupid, I want to just leave it there and maybe help other new guys in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&func` is in a *lambda-capture*. It means that the lambda will capture `func` by reference.

Without it, it captures by value which means making a copy of the object being referenced.

Comment: I agree most but "`The intent of the transform call is to modify the argument, so it must be captured by reference to achieve this.`", `transform` seems not modify a function, correct?

Comment: @NanXiao yes, you are right. It could be that the functor in question is non-copyable or they had some other reason for not wanting to copy it.